Lagrangian multiplier in Laplacian Eigenmap
I have some confusion regarding the the Laplacian Eigenmap Algorithm, The mathematics that I'm going through is the following:
The objective function that we want to minimize is expressed as:
$$
\min_{\text{f}}\sum_{i, j}W_{ij}(f_i - f_j)^2
$$

when the 2 points $i$ and $j$ are connected, we have $W_{ij} = 1$(in binary case), so we go for minimizing $(f_i - f_j)^2$, but when the two points are not connected, we have $W_{ij} = 0$.

We can rewrite the function as the following:
$$
\sum_{i, j}(f_i - f_j)^2W_{ij} = \sum_{i, j}(f_i^2 + f_j^2 - 2f_if_j)^2W_{ij} = \sum_{i, j}f_i^2W_{ij} + \sum_{i, j}f_j^2 W_{ij} - 2\sum_{i, j}f_i f_jW_{ij}
$$
We defined the matrix $D$ as $D_{ii} = \sum_{j}W_{ij}$, so can replace it in the above equation:
$$
\sum_{i, j}(f_i - f_j)^2W_{ij} = \sum_{i}f_i^2D_{ii} + \sum_{j}f_j^2 D_{jj} - 2\sum_{i, j}f_i f_jW_{ij}
$$
which is equal to ($L = D - W$):
$$
\sum_{i, j}(f_i - f_j)^2W_{ij} = 2\text{f}^{T}L\text{f}
$$
So, we reduce the optimization problem to the following:
$$
\min_{f}\sum_{i, j}(f_i - f_j)^2W_{ij} = \min_{\text{f}}\text{f}^{T}L\text{f}
$$
Now, we add a constraint to remove the arbitrary scaling in embedding:
$$
\min_{\text{f}}\text{f}^T L\text{f} \hspace{0.5cm}s.t. \hspace{0.25cm} \text{f}^TD\text{f} = 1
$$
The lagrangian of the optimization problem will be:
$$
\min_\text{f}\mathcal{L}(\text{f}, \lambda) = \text{f}^TL\text{f} - \lambda(\text{f}^TD\text{f} - 1)
$$
Next, we take the derivative with respect to $\text{f}$ and set it equal to $0$.
$$
\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial{\text{f}}} = 2L\text{f} - 2\lambda D\text{f} = 0
$$
Simplifying this, we get:
$$
L\text{f} = \lambda D\text{f}
$$
This is the generalized eigenvalue problem! The solution $\text{f}$ corresponds to the eigenvectors of this equation, and $\lambda$ corresponds to the eigenvalues.
In the algorithm, we select the $k$ smallest eigenvalues, ignoring the first one since it is zero, and consider the eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues. Why don't we consider the $k$ largest eigenvalues instead? Is this related to the Lagrange multiplier?
